# Do we create prototypes so we dont have to store methods in our constructor functions?

Tags: javascript, class, object, constructor, prototype

I am a tad confused , i think ive been given some wrong advice on here ( or advice which has confused me), in regards to  JavaScript prototypes for constructor functions. 1)  Do we create prototypes to make our constructor functions smaller and so that we dont have to store multiple methods inside of them that may not be used by each new object instance ? Or 2)  do we create prototypes to set up classes and then assign them to each object instance , so that they can access certain methods and not others. I was told option 2 but cant find evidence of this anywhere?

thanks all

Comment: It's unclear what you (or your advisor) mean by "*assign them to each object instance*" and "*so that they can access certain methods and not others*". Can you clarify, please?

Comment: his analogy was to think of it like a computer game, your not going to want to give all the characters the same methods otherwise the game will be boring, you want them to all do different things, so if you assign classes to different object instances ( variables) then each one has access to a bunch of properties that is specific to their funcionality, Although i have seen no evidence of this upon my rsearch , only that all methods are avaialbe to all instances ( variables ) attached to the prototype ! thanks for reply

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question about creating methods in the constructor or putting them on a prototype. To create different kinds of characters, you'd use different classes (constructors, prototypes) with different methods.

Answer (score 0):

Prototype methods will be on all instances. Methods created in constructors could also be on all instances, provided you don't have logic to conditionally not create them. Though creating them in the constructor would be creating a new unique version of the method for each instantiation, potentially.

Couple snippets demonstrating these mentioned differences.

## Prototype

```js
class Fun {
  constructor ( name ) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  sayHi () {
    console.log( `Hi ${this.name}!` );
  }
}

var fun1 = new Fun( 'james' );
var fun2 = new Fun( 'jill' );

fun1.sayHi();
fun2.sayHi();

console.log( 'Are they the same method in memory?', fun1.sayHi === fun2.sayHi );

console.log( 'Is the method shared?' );

delete Fun.prototype.sayHi;

try {
  fun1.sayHi();
} catch ( e ) {
  console.error( e );
}

try {
  fun2.sayHi();
} catch ( e ) {
  console.error( e );
}
```

## Constructor Defined

```js
class Fun {
  constructor ( name ) {
    this.name = name;
    
    this.sayHi = function () {
      console.log( `Hi ${this.name}` );
    };
  }
}

var fun1 = new Fun( 'james' );
var fun2 = new Fun( 'jill' );

fun1.sayHi();
fun2.sayHi();

console.log( 'Are they the same method in memory?', fun1.sayHi === fun2.sayHi );

console.log( 'Is the method shared?' );

delete fun1.sayHi;

try {
  fun1.sayHi();
} catch ( e ) {
  console.error( e );
}

try {
  fun2.sayHi();
} catch ( e ) {
  console.error( e );
}
```